# Foreach loop seems to have a syntax error?

Tags: php, android, mysql, foreach

Trying to make manageable output for Android to convert $output into JSONObjects. When I use the commented out bottom line, it receives the data in Android's log just fine, but can't convert JSONArray to JSONObject - thus the desire for a foreach loop to return each SQL row on its own. I can't see any syntax issues, so I don't know what PHP is complaining about - any ideas? Also, when I use the commented out print code, it returns proper results, so I know it's no problem accessing the db.
Here's the code:

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "*");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "*");
define("DB_DATABASE", "*");

mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
$sql=mysql_query("select * from QUESTIONS where CATEGORY like 'elections'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
foreach($output) {
echo $output;
}
mysql_close();


//print(json_encode($output));
?>
```

And here's the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/frehud/public_html/android_api/getQuestions/index.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `as` keyword and `assign` each value in a variable ($value here).Then `echo` that variable.

like below :

```
foreach($output as $value) {
echo $value;
}
```

Comment: This fixed the error, however, the output is not correct. When in a webpage, I get "ArrayArray" displayed once. I changed the echo line to print(json_encode($value)); while using your suggested syntax, and that printed out the tablerow contents. Thanks! I'll mark as answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the value assignment in the foreach loop.

Instead of `foreach($output)` you need to do something like this:

```
foreach($output as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

See [PHP - foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Yep one person above mentioned just this and it's the solution. I also had looked at that page to learn how to do a PHP for each loop, but misinterpreted what the parameters should have looked like! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the opening curly brace for the while loop:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
```

Should be:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
```

Also, you don't need the inner `foreach` loop, you should have access to row data via the `$row` variable populated in the while loop, like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {        
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: I added in a start and end brace for the while loop (assumed it didn't need one, as there was only one line/operation within the loop. Can't hurt to add these, however. Thanks!

Comment: Ya your right I didn't realize it until I looked at it closer. I stopped doing that a long time ago so I didn't end up confusing myself.

Comment: I still don't think you need the inner foreach loop though, you can get access at the $row data already. Unless you are trying to do something else?

Comment: Well, the ultimate goal here is to have Android reach each row and make some UI elements out of each row. I haven't sorted out how to do that yet, but at the moment, one big object in Android with the data from multiple rows is not what I want. Ideally, I want each row to be sent back to Android as an individual object that's easily parsed, etc.